How to reconnect bluetooth headphones after dual boot to Windows 11?
I have a dual boot setup with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04.
When I've been using my Bluetooth headphones (Sony wf-700cn) on Ubuntu and boot to Windows, I can reconnect fairly easily. Windows gives me a notification to configure the device, which then leads to a prompt asking whether I trust the device.
When connecting to my Android devices, all I need to do is go through the Bluetooth menu and tap on the device to reconnect.
When I want to connect my headphones on Ubuntu, going through Bluetooth settings to connect flashes the message "Connecting" and then goes back to "Disconnected". I need to remove the device, put the headphones into pairing mode, and then connect.
Is it possible to get do whatever it is that Windows and/or my Android devices do, so I can skip the pairing mode?
I've found this question that talks about a reverse problem, and this question where re-pairing does not solve the issue. Blueman does not work, it tells me br-connection-canceled, nor does manually trusting or setting the Name = Bluez in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf.

Follow the link I posted in the one linked question, it might be the issue in reverse but it is the easy way to fix

The solution, as Jeremy31 suggested in a comment, was to use bt-dualboot. What it does is copy your pairing keys from Linux to Windows. The easiest way to install it is
sudo apt install chntpw;
sudo pip install bt-dualboot;

So, what you need to do is pair your device in the Linux boot and make sure your Windows partition is mounted as readable. Then, execute sudo bt-dualboot -b --sync-all and you're good to go.
